# Python Adding a List of Class in Another Class

Tags: python

I have a class called Question as per below

```
class Question:
    q_count = 0
    def __init__(self, s_id, q_id, question):
        print("q count is ", Question.q_count)       
        self._s_id = s_id
        self._question_text = question
        self._answers = []
        self._q_id = Question.q_count

    def get_answers(self):
        return self._answers

    def set_answers(self,answers):
        self._answers = answers

    def add_answer(self, Answer()):
        self._answers.append(Answer())
```

and I want it to have a list called _answers which is a list of Answer objects. where Answer is another type of class i have created.

```
class Answer:
    def __init__(self, q_id, a_id):
        self._q_id = q_id
        self._a_id = a_id



# Subclass for multiple choice
class MC_Answer(Answer):
    def __init__(self, q_id, a_id, answer_text):
        Answer.__init__(self, q_id, a_id)
        self._answer_text = answer_text

    def get_answer_text(self):
        return self._answer_text

    def set_answer_text(self, a_id):
        self._a_id = a_id;
```

In another part of my code, I am creating an instance of an MC_Answer object. I also have an instance of a question object. How do I append this onto its answers list??

```
        answer1 = MC_Answer(idQ, 1, answer_text)
        new_q.add_answer(answer1)
        write_to_file(alist1, "answers.csv")
```

this is wrong but if i don't have answer1 as a parameter, how does Python know to add that particular instance of an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your add answer class never uses the parameter, instead you make a new instance of the Answer class and append that to the list, instead you need to modify it to give it a parameter and then use it correctly

```
def add_answer(self, Answer()):
    self._answers.append(Answer())
```

should be

```
def add_answer(self, answer):
    self._answers.append(answer)
```